# Azure Analysis Services versus Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services, azure-synapse

Can someone explain what is the difference between Azure Analysis Services and Azure Synapse Analytics? Why would one use Analysis Services over Synapse Analytics?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Azure Synapse Analytics is a rebrand of Azure SQL Data Warehouse (GA) with additional Analytics/Streaming/ML enhancements (currently at Public Preview).
[here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-data-warehouse-is-now-azure-synapse-analytics/)

Azure Analysis Services (AAS) is the Azure PaaS version for SQL Server Analysis Services.
[here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-analysis-services-preview/).

Please note -

> "Power BI Premium is the focus for enterprise BI and the primary
> target for future investments. In time, Power BI Premium will provide
> a superset of the capabilities when compared to Azure Analysis
> Services."
> [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-premium-and-azure-analysis-services/)

Comment: Thanks.  Can you share a use case where I would need both services? Would one use Azure Analysis Services on top of Synapse Analytics as an additional layer for tools like Power BI to consume?

Comment: The classic Microsoft on-prem architecture was SQL Server (DWH) + SQL Server Analysis Services. + Power BI. You could have copy-paste  this architecture to Azure using Azure SQL / Azure SQL Managed Instance / Azure SQL DWH aka Azure Synapse Analytics + Azure Analysis Services + Power BI. As I mentioned, the Power BI product group direction is to include the AAS capabilities as part of Power BI.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now.

Comment: Synapse also has an Apache Spark engine, so can potentially be a mechanism to migrate or blend the SQL Server world with the world of "Big Data". As well as access the myriad of ML models available in the Spark Universe.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Analysis Services -  can be used

- when small volume of data is to be analyzed,
- for detailed analysis,
- to form dashboard development,
- when concurrency required is high (thousands of users)

Azure Synapse Analytics - can be used

- when very high volumes of data is to be analyzed,
- when analysis involves complex queries,
- when concurrency required is low (128 users or few)
- for data mining.